# android layout stuff

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

If in a scrollview I have a relative layout with two textviews and one of the textview has property android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". It is possible to align this textview at the botton of the screen?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blabla"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="blabla2"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align TextView at the bottom, and rest of the ui to be scrollable. Then your layout should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="blabla" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="blabla2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want all my items scrollable because in the future may appear on the page multiple items, but I have to keep one item at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, what I understood from your comment, that you want n-1 items which are scrollable and nth item(in above case which is blabla2) should always be at bottom of the screen, means always visible to the user. If this is your case, then you just need to add all n-1 views in the RelativeLayout which is mentioned inside ScrollView. So, n-1 views will be scrollable and nth will always be fixed at the bottom.

Comment: so in my view must be 6 items. In portrait, the last one must be at the bottom of the screen (and them all fit in portrait mode for hdpi devices, fro mdpi them do not fit) but on landscape them do not fit so this is why I need to put them in a scrollview...

Comment: Okay gotcha, now I know what you mean. For this you should look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). And look for onConfigurationChanged() and you should also try to google for layout-land and layout-port mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). Hope this help you to resolve your issue.